# How to access properties of Get-Child Registry output

Tags: powershell, registry, get-childitem

Using the below code, I get `Name` & `LastLogon` populated, but not `ProfilePath`.

`Add-RegKeyMember` is https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Last-Write-Time-and-06dcf3fb .

I have tried to access `ProfileImagePath` with `$Profile.Properties.ProfileImagePath`, `$Profile.Name.ProfileImagePath`, and others, but they all return blank (could be null). How on earth is this seemingly object making these properties available?

```
$Profiles = get-childitem "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" | Add-RegKeyMember

foreach($Profile in $Profiles)
{

  $ThisProfileInfo = @{Name=$Profile.Name;
                     LastLogon=$Profile.LastWriteTime;
                     ProfilePath=$Profile.ProfileImagePath}
  $Profile
}

Name                           Property                                                                                                                                                       
----                           --------                                                                                                                                                       
S-1-5-18                       Flags            : 12                                                                                                                                          
                               ProfileImagePath : C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile                                                                                                    
                               RefCount         : 1                                                                                                                                           
                               Sid              : {1, 1, 0, 0...}                                                                                                                             
                               State            : 0
```

Comment: I guess you want to use a [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7): `$ThisProfileInfo = [pscustomobject]@{Name=$Profile.Name; ...}`. You might also use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7) to select specific properties of the `$Profiles` object.

Comment: @iRon - Sorry for not showing it, but Name and LastLogon get populated with expected values with the above syntax. Tried using `Select-Object` to obtain properties of `$Profile` (not sure the benefit of pulling them out of `$Profiles` when the foreach provides this access every other time I have used it in this way) without any different result to the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey] object returns properties as string array. You should simply retrieve the value ProfileImagePath from the object itself :

```
ProfilePath=$Profile.GetValue("ProfileImagePath")
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the below adjustments to your script.

You can pull the sub values of property by using the method `GetValue`.

I have also adjusted how you are storing each iteration and outputting the value post the `foreach` loop as the example above will just output each `$profile` as it was before the loop.

I have not tested with `Add-RegKeyMember` and therefore I am unable to confirm if this will pull the `LastWriteTime` property, but I can confirm that this will pull the `profileimagepath` property.

```
$Profiles = get-childitem "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" | Add-RegKeyMember

$ProfileData = @()

foreach($Profile in $Profiles){
    $ThisProfileInfo = $null

    $ThisProfileInfo = @{Name=$Profile.Name;
                 LastLogon=$Profile.GetValue("LastWriteTime");
                 ProfilePath=$Profile.GetValue("ProfileImagePath")}

    $ProfileData += $ThisProfileInfo
}

$ProfileData
```

Comment: Thanks CraftyB. Appreciate the effort to provide the rest of the script; Much of it (bar the good idea to `$null` missing $Profile object in any loop) is what I already had, but didn't think it was needed to see to answer the question.

Comment: There does seem to be an issue with both yours and mine still, though. I get `Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'Name'  Key being added: 'Name'` with either my or your script, and my data, at the += line. I wanted to have each loops hashtable added to an object to make it easy to pull out details of the various profiles, but `$ThisProfileInfo = new-object -Type PSObject -Property $ThisProfileInfo` right above the += line produces `A hash table can only be added to another hash table`. If you have any thoughts, let me know, otherwise I will ask another question.

Comment: Please ensure you have included the empty array `$ProfileData = @()` prior to the for each loop.

Comment: I had the wrong brackets (curly, not rounded), which when changed corrected both error messages. Thanks!